# Can も particle be used after adjective/verb + の?

Tags: grammar

If for example someone said :

> 彼はかっこいいね?

And I want to say 'he is also...' but I don't want to repeat the whole sentence like :

> 彼も優しいよね?

Can I just say :

> 優しいのも or 優しくても

To imply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

> しかも優しいよね

Here, しかも means "in addition" and the subject (彼は) is omitted.

---

Your attempts are not correct, though.

彼も優しいよね means "He, too, is a kind person." that is, someone is kind and also he is kind.

優しいのも or 優しくても doesn't make sense as a standalone sentence.

---

If you want to use も after adjectives or verbs, turn them into 連用形 as like 優しくも. You need an additional verb ある or する then. For example:

> 彼は優しくもある。

Comment: For clarification... I-adj : 面白い -> 面白くも. Na-adj : 静か -> 静かにも.  And verbs : 食べる -> 食べても/食べも.

Comment: Well, 面白い -> 面白くも(ある/する), 静かだ -> 静かでも(ある), 静かにも(する), and 食べる -> 食べも(する).